# Why do we use bootstrap method to get the SD here?

Tags: probability

**A certain town has 25,000 families. These families own 1.6 cars, on the average; the SD is 0.90. And 10% of them have no cars at all. As part of an opinion survey, a simple random sample of 1,500 families is chosen. What is the chance that between 9% and 11% of the sample families will not own cars?**

So I'm looking at the solution of this question it shows that to get the Standard Error of the Sum is SD= $\sqrt{0.9 \cdot\ 0.1} $ However, I thought the formula to get SE is:

SE= SD of the Box $\cdot\ $ $\sqrt{Number of Draws}$

In this case, isn't the **Box of the SD** given at 0.9? Why do we still use the bootstrap method to get SD= $\sqrt{0.9 \cdot\ 0.1} $=0.3 ??

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One is a normal distribution SD (0.9) and the other binomial (0.3). The problem has taken a normal distribution, the quantity of cars, and is asking a question of a binomial nature, yes or no to ownership.

Comment: ah I get it now thank you!